# Angular-translate: directives attribute without the filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Hi,

In angular-translate docs, it's [recommended for performance reasons](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive) to use `translate-attr` directive to translate attributes instead of the filter:

```html
<ANY translate-attr="{ ATTRIBUTE_NAME: 'TRANSLATION_ID' }"></ANY>
```

Ok, fine! The thing is it doesn't seem to work for directives  attributes. For example, with an AngularUI Bootstrap directive, this works:

```html
<uib-tab heading="{{ 'mytranslation'|translate }}"></uib-tab>
```

But this doesn't:

```html
<uib-tab translate-attr="{ heading: 'mytranslation' }"></uib-tab>
```

Am I doing something wrong or it can't be done for directives attributes due to their nature?

Comment: Nobody has a clue for this ? :)

Comment: Facing the same thing with ui-select, reported it here: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1577